# Android Google maps is not very responsive

Tags: android, geolocation, location, maps

I have implemented google maps in my android app. I am using geofencing to catch user's location and if he enters certain zones i make some api calls. This whole process runs in a foreground service because i want to run all the time even in the background. I also have google maps showing in the activity just for a better user experience.

The problem is that i notice that maps are very laggy. The blue dot moves slowly and when user enters a geolocation zone it takes 1 or 2 seconds and sometimes even more for the app to realize that it is actually there.

Same time if i open google maps application in the same phone with the same internet it runs very smoothly and the blue dot (my location) is very responsive even if i am not moving and just turn my phone left or right.

Is there something i can do to make google maps in my app faster and more responsive?

Comment: Add your code for others to review and help.

Comment: @AmarIlindra what code? it is just a fragment with google maps. nothing more. and it is very slow